# How to compress video captured used Subprocess adb screenrecord

Tags: python, adb, screen-recording

is there a way to determine maximum file size when recording Android devices screen using screenrecord?

This is the line I'm using to record my files. This is inside a python script

```
subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell", "screenrecord", "--verbose", device_file_name])
```

I'd like to determine maximum file size or at least, the bitrate

Answer (score 1):

You can see the available options you can use to set bit-rate or time limit if this is what you are looking for:

```
$ screenrecord --help
Usage: screenrecord [options] <filename>

Android screenrecord v1.3.  Records the device's display to a .mp4 file.

Options:
--size WIDTHxHEIGHT
    Set the video size, e.g. "1280x720".  Default is the device's main
    display resolution (if supported), 1280x720 if not.  For best results,
    use a size supported by the AVC encoder.
--bit-rate RATE
    Set the video bit rate, in bits per second.  Value may be specified as
    bits or megabits, e.g. '4000000' is equivalent to '4M'.  Default 20Mbps.
--bugreport
    Add additional information, such as a timestamp overlay, that is helpful
    in videos captured to illustrate bugs.
--time-limit TIME
    Set the maximum recording time, in seconds.  Default / maximum is 180.
--display-id ID
    specify the physical display ID to record. Default is the primary display.
    see "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id" for valid display IDs.
--verbose
    Display interesting information on stdout.
--help
    Show this message.

Recording continues until Ctrl-C is hit or the time limit is reached.
```